# IE not rendering certain divs

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

Yet another reason IE, as usual it's the only browser that fails to display my site correctly. I have a grid of divs, each with background images so they'll scale to fit the size of the div. But in IE, these divs are just failing to show up at all, I can't see any problems in the code that may be causing this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:
HTML

```
<div id="main-grid">

<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(IMAGE-URL-HERE)"></div>
<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(IMAGE-URL-HERE)"></div>
<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(IMAGE-URL-HERE)"></div>
<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(IMAGE-URL-HERE)"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-grid {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-block {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 315px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It might be something completely obvious that I'm missing, but I can't seem to figure out why these divs are failing to show up in IE.

Comment: What version IE are you using?

Comment: @suspectus I'm testing in IE9, I don't use it though ;) any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Nor do I :) 
What DOCTYPE? Have you tried <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: @suspectus yes it's DOCTYPE html, it's a CMS on WP. Although if as some people have stated here, the blocks are rendering in IE9 it may have something to do with the jQuery plugin being used to layout the divs, the isotope plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html Is there a possibility the jQuery is causing some problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty `DIV` are not rendered in standard HTML. That might be your problem.
I tested it with your case, but some content in the `DIV` tags and all was fine.

My Sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #main-grid {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .grid-block {
        display: table;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 315px;
        height: 220px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-grid">

    <div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(http://www.heise.de/icons/ho/heise_online_logo_top.gif)">a</div>
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(http://www.heise.de/icons/ho/heise_online_logo_top.gif)">b</div>
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(http://www.heise.de/icons/ho/heise_online_logo_top.gif)">c</div>
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url(http://www.heise.de/icons/ho/heise_online_logo_top.gif)">d</div>

  </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Any content inside the div, empty spans e.g. will do.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, this isn't the problem though, as some divs do have content in them. thus the reason I've used background images as most of the divs have text on top, centred horizontally and vertically, thus my decision to use tables. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the isotope plugin which is used to layout the divs? Or just a css problem